# trouble customizing a page.tpl.php for Drupal 7 page callback to serve a form over AJAX

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I am creating a custom module. I want to implement a form that can be used as a block, and used in a query dialog (loaded with an ajax request). I have created the block no problem. I have also created the page callback function no problem.

So, I can load the form in a block and I can pull up the jquery dialog and it will get the form with an ajax request. But, It loads the form and the full page template complete with header and footer etc....

What I want to do is use a different page template when getting the ajax call so that all I get is the form. But, everything I've seen online seems to be a mix between drupal 6 and 7 and I haven't gotten anything to work.

here's my latest try:

in menu hook

```
  $items['mymodule/get_form_ajax'] = array( 
    'title' => 'Ajax Form',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'get_form_ajax',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
```

Then I have the callback:

```
function get_form_ajax() {
    $form = drupal_get_form('request_form');
    $build['items'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'request_form',
        '#items' => $form,
    );
    return $build;
}
```

And then I have the theme registered this way:

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'request_form' => array(
      'template' => 'request_form', 
      'render element' => 'form', 
    )
  );
}
```

Anyway, this totally doesn't work. It just renders an empty page in the dialog. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're making an AJAX call there's no need to let the page build as normal, you can simply print the rendered form out directly and call `drupal_exit()`:

```
function get_form_ajax() {
  $form = drupal_get_form('request_form');
  echo render($form);

  drupal_exit();
}
```

This will give you a nice clean form that inherits the styles from the page it's being loaded into, and still keeps the form tokens/cache in-tact.

Comment: yep! That's perfect. Thanks Clive.